# User is missing identities in policy with authentication scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I've created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application that uses 2 authentication types - cookie and JWT bearer.

I've setup a scheme that redirects users to the proper scheme based on the path requested:

```
.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = "smart";
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "smart";
})
.AddPolicyScheme("smart", "Bearer Authorization or Cookie", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        var requestPath = context.Request.Path;

        if (CookiePolicyPathRegex.IsMatch(requestPath))
        {
            return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }

        return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    };
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOAuthServiceScheme(Configuration); // Custom handler for JWT
```

I setup the authorization policies like so:

```
options.AddPolicy(ApiPolicies.CookiePolicy, policy =>
{
    // policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    policy.RequireRole(Roles.Access);
});

options.AddPolicy(ApiPolicies.JwtPolicy, policy =>
{
    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
});
```

This works fine, the proper policies are being triggered, but I have one problem. In my integration tests I use a middleware that adds the ClaimsIdentity for the cookie authentication:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    //  Removed for brevity

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

    await _next(context);
}
```

The middleware is setup to run before the Auth middlewares

```
ConfigureAdditionalMiddleware(app);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

If I uncomment the `// policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` part from the cookie policy, the the authorization part doesn't see the Identity created in the middleware. If I leave it commented, the Identity is there, with claims, authentication type and everything. If I look in the PolicyScheme that forwards to the two auth schemes, the Identity is there.

**My question is, why does adding `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` somehow hide the User Identity that was created with the same authentication type?**

Comment: Is it possible you place your middleware after `UseAuthentication` middleware so identity isn't set yet?

Comment: Good point, I edited the post to include that part of Startup.cs, but the way I see it it should be fine. The Identity is visible in the scheme that forwards to the auth schemes

Comment: Identity can be set in both ```UseAuthentication``` and in ```UseAuthorization```, see this post to learn more about what exactly ```UseAuthentication``` does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836688/what-exactly-is-useauthentication-for/59233644#59233644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization middleware will evaluate your policy and will run the authentication logic which will override the user.Context

- See source code here
  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6c7a8bb397de1fcfeeb6510ea39ef6eb02c15352/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs

Here is the relevant code snippet (I removed and simplified the code to highlight the relevant parts):

```
public virtual async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
{
    if (policy.AuthenticationSchemes != null && policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Count > 0)
    {
        var newPrincipal = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme).Principal;

        if (newPrincipal != null)
        {
            context.User = newPrincipal;
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(newPrincipal, string.Join(";", policy.AuthenticationSchemes)));
        }
        else
        {
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So, as you can see, when you define a scheme for your policy, then you enter the "if" statement (which will set a new `context.User`, and if you comment the line, the authentication logic will not run and your custom user object will be there

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research! I figured it would be something like this. So the only way to make it work in tests would be to fabricate an actual cookie an send it in the request? I would love to be able to keep adding the scheme in the policy so I can tie it to cookie options.

Comment: Cookie fabrication will be quite difficult to build since you'll have to understand the internals of the cookie auth + the cookie symmetric encryption/decryption key.